# Get all the Text from a xml file

Tags: python, xml, text

I want to extract all the text in a XML-File with Python.

Is there any possibility?

I heard that it is possible with using 
xml.etree.ElementTree

For example:

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I just want to extract:
1 
2008
141100
4
2011
and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
from xml-etree.ElementTree import parse

tree = parse('data.xml') #extract the file (change the name to your file name)

for e in tree.findall('year') #searches the content of all the tags 'year' 
    print(e.text)
```

You can also store the value in a dict with the key equal to the name of the country and the value equal to a list of all the attributes

Comment: Does not work. `open` should be `parse`. And there are no `title` elements in the XML document in the question.

Comment: 'title' was just a random name i put. In your case you can put rank, year, neighbor ecc..

Comment: sorry i took this from an old script i made a while ago.

Comment: The code still has at least two syntax errors. Why don't you test it before posting?